# "Fantastical" Geology in Sci-Fi?

Tags: planets, gravity, geology

For a story of mine, I wanted to include the kind of "unnatural" - at least for Earth - geology that you sometimes see in sci-fi. Meaning in this case massive stone spires or land bridges spanning the sky for several kilometers.

My problem is that I'm not actually sure if such natural structures could exist on alien worlds.

Comment: You state yourself that they are unnatural, so why are you worried that they might not exist?

Comment: I meant unnatural in regards to earth, might have to clarify that . . .

Comment: Please describe the basic conditions of the alien world. How strong is the gravitational acceleration on the surface, what's the density of the atmosphere, how strong are the winds... On an Earth-like world we cannot make a bridge span of "several kilometers" with the best of modern engineering... The longest bridge span worldwide, part of the Akashi-Kaikyo Bridge, is a little less than 2 km.

Comment: Stone Spires exist on Earth, such as the famous Buttes of Monument Valley or Devils Tower/Bear Lodge of Wyoming.   The former are weathered sandstone, while the latter is a vein of magma that cooled and was exposed when the volcano was weathered away.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Giant rock spikes sticking out of the ground](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/142604/giant-rock-spikes-sticking-out-of-the-ground)

Comment: I voted to close. This is a good question in theory, and I want you to re-ask it as a couple separate questions. 1) How can I get a world with giant spires? 2) How can I get a world with lots of natural bridges?  If you have other specific structures, ask them separately. I believe we will get better answers by having the group focus on specific goals rather than the generic “alien landscape”.

Answer (score 1):

"The aliens did it" is always a good get out for fantastical structures, but if you want natural structures then gravity is not kind to huge arches and spires. They can exist to a certain degree for a while here (monument valley and similar) but truly massive monolithic structures probably wouldn’t work in an Earth like setting for the same reason that we don’t see them on Earth.

That said there might be some hope. A lower gravity world would help, also rather than using very hot explosively energetic lave to build mountains perhaps a different liquid at a lower temperature might be better suited to creating spires? If a liquid, say water were to come out of the ground under pressure on a very cold world it would freeze, but it might not behave in the same way as lava does on Earth. There might be scope for it to build a very steep cone or spire. If water didn’t work then salty water, mud, ammonia, carbon dioxide or any other simple compound might.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a question for you-- do the features have to be on the planet's surface? What about giving the planet rings and/or multiple moons that can observed at various times in the night and day sky? Those are naturally occurring in our own solar system, but they would make the skyline seem drastically different and alien.

How about something like a magnetic aurora? The Aurora Borealis is native to Earth, and appears as green lights in the night sky, but there's nothing preventing you from having a significantly different atmospheric composition that might result in blue, pink, red, etc. lights on the horizon. Maybe even all manner of different colored lights at the same time!

Now, as for an incredible landscape on the planet's surface-- could something have changed relatively recently on the planet? What if we've seen shifts in the water cycle, and now we're getting acidic rain that bores raindrop-like holes in mountains, and carves rivets through the earth?

What if plant life is especially tenacious and relatively new? We could have something akin to a tree splitting a massive rock formation in half, with only the roots stopping it from crashing down to the ground!

What if the plants themselves are the incredible feature as opposed to geology? Plants might easily grow together into the sort of archways that you'd see, with inter-connected branch and canopy ecosystems that would be foreign to us from an earthling perspective. The forest could even have become petrified over time, giving you both a more geological feature and a sense of vague doom ("What happened to make something as biologically diverse as the Amazon turn to stone here?")

What's the mineral composition of this planet? Could you have lots of gallium or mercury, both of which are metals with very low melting points, and both of which would make eerie, metallic lakes? Could you have a liquid metal waterfall as a frozen glacier of mercury slowly melts away at the top of a mountain?

Crystals form naturally throughout nature. If there's a massive rift in the ground, such as something like the Grand Canyon, could it be filled with crystalline structures? They come in a variety of shapes and sizes, and can range from cube-shaped fractals to hexagonal prisms-- pretty much anything your mind can imagine, it's an actual-factual scientific crystal.

Is a large portion of the ground an oxidizing compound? Kicking up the dirt could reveal a vibrantly different color than what you were standing on before, only for it to react with the air above and quickly turn to whatever color the oxide was.